# Installing Integration Services for Hyper-V into CentOS-5.x

Tags: centos, hyper-v, centos5

I am trying to install Linux Integration Services v2.1 into CentOS 5.5 running on Hyper-V.  I have followed the dkms instructions from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2387594

This works, in that I can install the services and then reboot the VM, and everything works.

The problem is that if I do a `yum update` that picks up a new kernel (today it is 2.6.18-238.5.1.el5, but previous update kernels don't work) the server doesn't boot.  It stops on an APIC error:

```
ENABLING IO-APIC IRQs
..Timer: vector=0x31 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
..MP-BIOS bug: 8254 timer not connected to IO-APIC
...trying to set up timer (IRQ0) through 8259A ... failed.
...trying to set up timer as Virtual Wire IRQ ... failed.
...trying to set up timer as ExtINT IRQ... failed :(
Kernel panic - not syncing: IO-APIC + timer doesn't work!  Boot with apic=debug
and send a report.  Then try booting with the 'noapic' option
```

So if I reboot and manually edit the command line to include the `noapic` option, the VM boots and does whatever DKMS magic is required to get everything going again; subsequent boots are successful without the `noapic` option.

So my question is:

Is there a way to avoid the manual-boot-with-noapic step when the kernel upgrades itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heres what you probably need instead.

[Installing Centos 5.5 with Integration Components 2.1](http://www.jcarle.com/2010/12/06/installing-centos-5-5-with-linux-integration-services-2-1-on-hyper-v-r2/)

You might also want this, I get this error every time when I install Centos 5.5

[Locating and adding depmod to the path.](http://www.sudonym.com/392/adding-a-directory-to-linux-path-environment-variable)

Edit: I just performed a yum update over the weekend on a cou ple systems and everything went nice and cleanly.

Comment: This is almost what I was doing before the dkms came along.  If you follow these instructions you'll end up in the same boat -- the kernel won't boot after new kernels get upgraded.

Comment: Marking as correct since I've done a few since then and they all work properly.  So I probably messed something up on the problem one above.